# How can I set double value in seekbar

Tags: android, integer, double, seekbar

I want to use seek bar in my application but I should set double value in my seek bar. However Integer is a default value. I can parse it but I will lose data because of that how can I change default value from integer to double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without coding your own SeekBar you can't. If your value ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 set max value for SeekBar to 10 and multiply your value by 10, for 0.00 to 1.00 by 100 and so on.